# Index and searching the file i need

Tags: solr

suppose i have a pdf file containing info like a CV -

Name: xyz
DOB: 11/11/1980
email:xyz@yzx.com

objective:xyz abc....

skills: c++ c java xml etc

education: 
college name university
Result: 9

work experience/technical activities/internships :  xyz abc def ...

activities/interests/sports : abc ..

Reference : xyz
Declaration: I here by  .....

---

I want to index similar pdf files in solr. I am new to this.
So can anyone insist me what exactly i need to do.
how to index. I just know that i have to use curl command. But I dont know wat changes or additions I have to make in schma.xml and solrconfig.xml to index this file and query for some exact things.

I want to do some tasks such as finding names of people who have java as their skills.
and i just need their names and skills to be displayed as the result.

Please do help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solr, you store your data as a Solr document. Each document consist of an **id** and multiple fields. For each field you can store your data.

1. [Read here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) and design your custom schema. You should have all the fields on which you want to query.
2. Index your data into Solr. Following 2 URL will guide you how to index data and extract document.
   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages
   http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler
3. Finally [query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters)

Hope these will be able to guide you.

Comment: Sorry to ask basic question. For the above example should I add fields in the schema.xml file ?
<field name="skills" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

is this the way ?? Please help me with respect to the above ex. of pfd file

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. First, finalize what various types of query you'll do on each type of data. Then, add field to your schema.xml with proper field type.

Comment: Ok thanks.. Is that all ? Do i need to add in anything else in solrconfig.xml or in any other files ?

Comment: I think nothing else. If your are finding the answer useful to you, then accept it and upvote the answer.

Comment: and a last doubt. If i want to index pdf dynamically, I mean i wont be knowing the exact contents. so is there any way to set a good schema.xml so that it can handle any content in the file? right now I am getting entire text when i query. I want only the text around the word i query. Please help. Thanks